# SQL: send query to all database available

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

How is it possible to send a query to all databases on a server? I do not want to input all databases names, the script should auto-detect them.

example query:

```
SELECT SUM(tourney_results.amt_won)-SUM((tourney_summary.amt_buyin+tourney_summary.amt_fee)) as results
FROM tourney_results
INNER JOIN tourney_summary
ON tourney_results.id_tourney=tourney_summary.id_tourney
Where id_player=(SELECT id_player FROM player WHERE player_name='Apple');
```

So what I want to achieve here, if there is 2 databases, the first one would result 60, the second one would result 50, I need the 55 output here.

All databeses would have the same structure, tables etc.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using plpgsql and [db_link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html). First install the db_link extension in the database you are connecting to:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Then use a plpgsql function which iterates over all database on the server and executes the query. See this example (see comments inline). Note that I used a sample query in the function. You have to adapt the function with your real query:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_dblink() RETURNS BIGINT AS
  $$
DECLARE pg_database_row record;
        query_result BIGINT;
        _dbname TEXT;
        _conn_name TEXT;
        return_value BIGINT;
BEGIN
    --initialize the final value
    return_value = 0;
    --first iterate over the records in the meta table pg_database
    FOR pg_database_row in SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE (NOT datistemplate) AND (datallowconn) LOOP

      _dbname = pg_database_row.datname;
      --build a connection name for db_link
      _conn_name=_dbname||'myconn';
      --close the connection is already active:
      IF array_contains(dblink_get_connections(),_conn_name) THEN
        PERFORM dblink_disconnect(_conn_name);
      END IF;

      -- open the connection with the actual database name
      PERFORM dblink_connect(_dbname||'myconn', 'dbname='||_dbname);
      -- check if the table does exist in the database:
      PERFORM * FROM dblink(_conn_name,'SELECT 1 from pg_tables where tablename = ''your_table''') AS t(id int) ;
      IF FOUND THEN
        -- if the table exist, perform the query and save the result in a variable
        SELECT * FROM dblink(_conn_name,'SELECT sum(id) FROM your_table limit 1') AS t(total int) INTO query_result;
         IF query_result IS NOT NULL THEN
           return_value = return_value + query_result;
         END IF;
      END IF;
      PERFORM dblink_disconnect(_conn_name);

    END LOOP;
RETURN return_value;
END;
    $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Execute the function with

```
select test_dblink();
```